# Map an Array of objects from Firebase to List Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve an array of objects from Firebase and store it in Flutter Object as a List.

This is the collection, Firebase,

[image: Firebase]

And this is the model class

```
class Merchant {
  String shopName;
  String address;
  String description;
  String thumbNail;
  LatLng locationCoords;

  Merchant( 
      {this.shopName,
      this.address,
      this.description,
      this.thumbNail,
      this.locationCoords});
}


final List<Merchant> merchant = [];      // Map it to This List
```

I'd like to map it into this list above

```
    final List<Merchant> merchant = [];
```

Comment: Have you looked at the Firestore documentation for Flutter? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I can't seem to figure out how to Map it from the docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First add this method to your Merchant class:

```
Merchant.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    shopName = map['shopName'];
    address = map['address'];
    description = map['description'];
    thumbnail = map['thumbnail'];
    locationCoords = map['locationCoords'];
  }
```

This method will then be used to write the data into the Merchant Class/Struct.

Retrieving the data the could look something like the following:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

CollectionReference merchRef = _firestore.collection('merchants'));


Future<List<Merchant>> getAllMerchants() async {
  List<Merchant> merchantList = [];
  
  await merchRef.get().then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
      Merchant merchant = Merchant.fromMap({
        'shopName': doc['shopname'],
        'address': doc['address'],
        'description': doc['description'],
        'thumbnail': doc['thumbnail'],
        'locationCoords': doc['location'],
      });
      merchantList.add(merchant);
    });
  });

 return merchantList;
}
```

P.S.:
Haven´t tried this out yet and you might need some parsing for locationCoords, since it is of type LatLng.

Comment: for Location I used  `LatLng(doc)['latitude'], doc)['longitude']),` Working now thanks